# Creating a dynamic sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Please see this SQL code:

```
DECLARE @MyQuery nvarchar(max)
set @MyQuery = 'SELECT TOP 1 @TranslatedMessageOutput = 
               ' + @LanguageName + ' FROM local_translation WHERE English =
               '+CHAR(39)+CHAR(39)+Convert(nvarchar(50),
               (select English from inserted))
                +CHAR(39)+CHAR(39)+CHAR(39)+
               ' AND [' + @LanguageDateName + '] NOT LIKE ''%1900%'''
```

If I type `abc` for English this query works just fine.

But if I type `'abc'` for English the query is throwing an error:

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string "". Incorrect syntax near "."

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you will need to escape the output of this query:

```
(select English from inserted)
```

As in

```
(select replace(English, '''', '''''') from inserted)
```

The above will replace `'` by `''` before concatenating the outcome to your dynamic SQL statement. But with any dynamic SQL, I strongly suggest you make use of bind values to prevent such SQL syntax errors and SQL injection! I.e. you should be able to write something like this:

```
declare @English;
select @English = English from inserted;
set @MyQuery = 'SELECT TOP 1 @TranslatedMessageOutput = 
               ' + @LanguageName + 
               ' FROM local_translation WHERE English = @English'
               ' AND [' + @LanguageDateName + '] NOT LIKE ''%1900%''';
-- ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dynamic sql queries in order to avoid confusion ,use `Char(39)` instead of `'`.
Eg :

```
SET @T='SELECT '+CHAR(39)+'NAME'+CHAR(39)
```

returns

```
SELECT 'NAME'
```