# how to use variable name as table name in update statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, dynamic-sql

I have a table(Lets say'A') that contains the list of all tables in a database.I have defined a cursor that iterate through the tables name in 'A'.I want to update the table column defined in a cursor.

I have created 2 cursors.One to iterate over the tables names and other one to iterate over the column names.

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField nvarchar(255);

BEGIN
SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
select distinct Table_name from DataTable where Data <>'No'
set @a=0
OPEN @MyCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
INTO @MyField

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @column_cursor CURSOR;
    DECLARE @columnField nvarchar(255);
    SET @column_cursor = CURSOR FOR
    select Column_name from DataTable where TABLE_NAME=@MyField and Data 
    <>'No'


        OPEN @column_cursor 
        FETCH NEXT FROM @column_cursor 
        INTO @columnField
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN


    update  @MyField set @columnField=''+@MyField+'_'+@columnField+@a
             FETCH NEXT FROM @column_cursor 
             INTO @columnField 
         END;
       CLOSE @column_cursor ;
       DEALLOCATE @column_cursor;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
  INTO @MyField 
END; 

CLOSE @MyCursor ;
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
```

END;

Here in the update statement @MyField is giving error :"Must declare the table variable @MyField".

Comment: You have to use set instead of Update, because @MyField is a variable

Comment: You cannot parameterize object names. In this situation, you will need to use dynamic sql. And ignoring the suspicious path, use descriptive and relevant variable names. MyField is not a field or a column, it is the name of a table. And be consistent! You terminate some statements but not all?

Comment: And you don't need two cursors - using one cursor will be just as <in>efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are on good way but you can't use variable on table name place , you need to build your update command  in variable and then execute  dynamic sql. 
You can see: [Creating a dynamic sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20310051/creating-a-dynamic-sql-query)

in your case someting like

```
declare @sqlCommand varchar(max)
declare @MyField varchar(255) = 'table_name' 
declare @columnField varchar(255) = 'column_NAME'
declare @columnValue varchar(255) = 'column_value'

set @sqlCommand = 'update '+ @MyField +' set '+@columnField+' = ' +@columnValue+ ' where 1=1;'
--select @sqlCommand
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```